# Associate Professors without a PhD?

Tags: phd, canada, assistant-professor, lecturer, associate-professor

The title "Associate Professor", which is commonly used in North America, is "[usually connected to tenure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_professor)" in that it is almost exclusively given to tenured or permanent professors who are higher in rank than Assistant Professors. This has also been explained in previous Academia.SE questions, for example:

- (1) [Associate Professor to Assistant Professor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/138416/93303)
- (2) [Assistant professor vs Associate professor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/assistant-professor-vs-associate-professor)

Within the last year, someone also asked here about the awarding of the Associate Professor title to people without doctorates: [Is it true, that there are associate professors, full professors and University provosts without a doctorate in the Western Continental Europe?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/165611/93303), and we learned there that in UK there are Professorships awarded in Law and Engineering (and I wouldn't be surprised if also in Medicine) to people without doctorates.

I wonder if there's any precedent for people being given this title ***without a PhD*** in Canada? I wouldn't be surprised if people have this title after getting a JD, MD, PharmD, PEng, etc., so even more specifically **I am wondering about people who have only an undergrad degree  and/or Masters.**

The reason for my question, is because it looks like a U15 university in Canada (I might as well just say openly that it's University of Waterloo) says that they will be re-labeling Continuing Lecturers into Associate Professors:

[image]

Continuing Lecturers (soon to become Associate Professors), often enough do not have a PhD (for example [here](http://wolczuk.com/CV.pdf) and [here](https://uwaterloo.ca/applied-mathematics/people-profiles/joe-west)). I understand that other Canadian universities (e.g. University of Toronto and McMaster University) also have the "teaching-stream Professor" positions, but [advertisements for applying to those positions](https://www.academicwork.ca/jobs/teaching-stream-assistant-professor-in-psychology-mcmaster-university) suggest that a PhD is required.

Since Charles Grant astutely [pointed out](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/180563/associate-professors-without-a-phd?noredirect=1#comment484465_180563) that Freeman Dyson's full professorship at Cornell was without a PhD, I'd like to be clear that I'm not looking for "one-time exceptional cases" that lasted only 1 year and went to someone who helped Feynman get the Nobel Prize,  but more for "regular" positions that are offered frequently (e.g. there's at least one job advertisement at the university per year for a job with the "Associate Professor" title).

Comment: You are explicitly asking about not just people without PhD degrees but also people without equivalent terminal degrees in other fields like medicine and law?  So why do you keep reverting the question to say "PhD" in the title?

Comment: @Buzz My question is about people without PhDs, and I've now edited the question to say "*even more specifically*" I'd be interested in cases where people only have up to a Masters degree. The phrase "terminal degree" has [multiple issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/180563/93303), and most people don't know what exactly it means (including me). I want my question to be understood by people who see it. I don't know if switching "PhD" to "terminal degree" in my question is the most productive, because a BSc or Masters could be considered a terminal degree.

Comment: What "multiple issues"?  It is standard terminology for degrees like M.D., J.D., M.F.A., etc.  And people with those kinds of degrees routinely get professorships (assistant, associate, full—the requirements are essentially the same for each of them in North America) teaching in the specific associated fields.

Comment: @Buzz Please, let's not argue. This is my question and I don't want to get into an edit war. The question is about Canada where: "The term is not generally used in the United Kingdom or Canada, for example, and its exact meaning varies somewhat between those areas and disciplines in which the term is used" plus there's higher degrees than PhD, such as Habilitation degrees. I'd appreciate if we can leave the question alone unless it's standards are below the average acceptable level on this site. I did include your edit about "there is" vs "there are".

Comment: @Buffy Wow, thanks for noticing that! I have no idea how that happened! I guess I won't be getting the [spotless hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list) for writing a question with no edits for one week!

Comment: If this is really a question about a single university, then it is really off topic here. But the doctorate isn't necessarily the highest qualification in every field. Dance, music, law, medicine (depending on your definition), art, others perhaps.

Comment: @Buffy I know what you mean, but this question is about **all** universities in Canada. The motivation for it came from something I noticed at one university, but I'm wondering if there's precedent for it anywhere in Canada.

Comment: It's a US counter-example, so not strictly an answer to  your question, but Freeman Dyson was a full professor of Physics, first at Cornell, then at the Institute of Advanced Studies at Princeton. Dyson had only a B.A. degree from Cambridge, but already had a significant body of work. I think universities can find their way around nominal requirements for scholars of exceptional achievement.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant That's a very good example. Until he died last year, Freeman Dyson was labeled in my research field as "the greatest living physicist" for many years. Dyson surely had a "special" position at Cornell. Perhaps I should improve my question further by restricting it to "general" positions that are part of the university's policy, meaning that they're regularly appointed (not a one-time thing like Dyson).

Comment: It sounds like Waterloo is just giving a fancy-sounding name for an existing position, likely without materially changing anything about the nature of the position, the required qualifications, or the implications for how impressive a person is for holding that position. Also, the fancy-sounding name is “Associate Professor, Teaching Stream”, not “Associate Professor”. So in other words, I don’t see why it matters whether such a thing has precedent or not in Canada, as it’s a move that would be of very little interest to anyone, perhaps including even holders of this position.

Comment: (…That being said, your question is a legitimate question, so best of luck getting an answer.)

Comment: @DanRomik Thanks! It's happened at McMaster and University of Toronto too, and maybe will soon happen to others too, so that's largely why I was asking. The conditions of the job will change slightly, but not enough for me to mention it in this question. You're right that it's called "Associate Professor - Teaching Stream" but ***practically*** they'll be addressed as "professors" and most people, especially external people, will not know to include "Teaching Stream" in the title, or understand/appreciate what it means.

Comment: Sounds like a textbook example of [job title inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_title_inflation).

Answer (score 4):

There are many precedents, especially in the older (possibly now retired) ranks.  During the 70s and 80s, there was considerable expansion of the sector and some positions were filled by candidates without PhDs.

This is much less common now because of the oversupply of PhDs in basically every discipline.  As with anything there are exceptions so I’m sure it is still possible to get tenure without a PhD, based on the body of work.  I can imagine for instance that some departments (*v.g.* law, political sciences, music, art) would hire experts (former ambassadors, politicians, other public figures) as faculty members, based primarily on their professional expertise and experience rather than their academic qualifications.  However, such higher profile hires rarely get tenure by progress through the ranks: they will usually be hired with tenure.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer! Are you able to give specific examples of people at the Associate Professor level (not including "Adjunct Associate Professor" or "Visiting Associate Professor") without a PhD (apart from fields like law, medicine, music, art, clinical psychology etc., where work experience is considered more important for teaching)? The more recent the example the better, because if something happened in the 70s then I'm not *too* fussed about it today.

Comment: I do not know of a recent example, at least my field of Physics or cognate fields like Chemistry, Math or Comp.Sci.  Even teaching stream positions require a PhD.  I know of one former colleague (retired ~ 10 years ago) who only completed an MSc and was full. prof in comp.sci, but things have changed so much there it isn’t representative.